# application cannot get the running AppImage path

Tags: qt, appimage

In my application, sometimes I need to find out the path of the application executable. I use `QApplication::applicationFilePath()` and it works fine. But when I distribute my application as AppImage on Linux, this breaks. It returns the path where the running AppImage was mounted, e.g. `/tmp/.mount_MyAppxyzabc/MyApp`. But I would need to get the path of the AppImage itself, e.g. `/home/vlad/MyApp/MyApp.AppImage`. Is this possible to obtain from inside the running application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly found the answer and I will leave it here for others. At least for AppImages deployed by `linuxdeployqt` (not sure about other AppImages), the path to the appimage is in environment variable $APPIMAGE.

So in my code I use:
`QString appImagePath = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().value(QStringLiteral("APPIMAGE"));`

The returned string however ends with path separator '/' so I need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The code above doesn't work for me.  appImagePath is set to an empty QString.  Also, the following:

```
QProcessEnvironment env(QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment());
QStringList tt = env.keys();
QFile outFile("./debug.txt");
outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream out(&outFile);
for (QStringList::iterator it = tt.begin(); it != tt.end(); ++it)
    out << *it << " " << env.value(*it) << endl;
outFile.close();
```

works for me in my release build, but doesn't in the appImage

This is on Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31011685)